# Google charts - Y axis value and actual value doesnt match

Tags: google-visualization

As you can see from the link the max value is about 250 when it should be 999(see data below).
Why is this and what do I do about it?

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxt=y&chd=e:AMAPAWAqAgGfPnPnLS&chxr=0,0,1000
,200&chco=76a4fb&chs=600x300&cht=lc&chtt=Some+graph&chls=1.0

```
import GChartWrapper as C

def makeGraph(maxY, stepY):
    data = [12,15,22,42,32,415,999,999,722]
    G = C.Line(data, encoding='extended')
    G.color('76A4FB')
    G.line(1)
    G.axes('y')
    G.axes.range(0,0,maxY,stepY)
    G.size(600,300)
    G.title("Some graph")
    return G

g = makeGraph(1000,200)

print ""

print g

print ""
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this problem out??

Answer (score 0):

This is a little different than the problem that I ran into but this may help.  In google charts api you have to sent the axis range parameter to

`&chds=a`

There is likely an equivalent for your issue.